# Next start is not working (Next dev works)

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js, webstorm

I have a problem I can't run my Next.js project with the `next start` command. Everything works for `next dev` command.

My environment: node v20.9.0

package.json file

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "14.0.1",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.69.5",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

I tried to remove globally installed Node and then installed it via NVM. I tried also Node v18.

P.S. I am writing command in WebStorm. In terminal after `next start` I am getting "zsh: command not found: next".

Comment: I solved the issue after running next build. Seems that "next start" should have BUILD_ID to run the project in production mode.